# Can I set a limit of 2 entries on Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I use Google Forms in my classroom to administer certain quizzes, however, I allow my students two attempts on these. I have noticed that I am unable to see how may actual attempts have been made and suspect that I have a couple who may do them more than the two times allowed. I would like to be able to set this limit if possible so that this is not a loophole.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a a single form. One alternative is to have two copies of your quiz a limit both of them to allow only one submission for each respondent.